# Error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to compile this code that uses the opencv Library

```
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
XX=[]

for i in range(len(K_points)):
      XX.append(K_points[i])
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(np.float32(XX),len(K_points),None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
```

**Error:**

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.